# Selecting from Type 2 Dimension based Report Start and End Date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-2-dimension

I have a large Type 2 Dimension table and causing performance issues in the select queries...I want to limit the Dimensions based on the report Start and End Dates ...But I am struggling to get the right query for that...Here is an example of what I am looking for...

```
    declare @DimCustomers table (CKey int, ID nvarchar(20), Customer nvarchar(50), StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)

insert into @DimCustomers values
(100, 'C1', 'Customer1', '2010-01-01', '2010-12-31'),
(101, 'C1', 'xCustomer1', '2011-01-01', '2011-12-31'),
(102, 'C1', 'xxCustomer1', '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'),
(103, 'C1', 'xxxCustomer1', '2013-01-01', NULL)

declare @ReportStartDate datetime = '2010-05-01', @ReportEndDate datetime = '2011-03-01'

select 
* from @DimCustomers
```

The expectation is that when someone runs a report between '2010-02-01' and '2011-02-01', I get an out put for Ckey 100 and 101.

For  a report between '2011-02-01' and current date -> 101, 102 and 103

For  a report between '2015-02-01' and current date -> 103

I hope that explains what I am looking for...how should my WHERE clause look like on the @DimCustomers?

Thanks

Note: I do not want to join with the Fact Table to start with...

Answer (score 0):

You have `NULL` value in EndDate. You will have to deal with it.
For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM @DimCustomers
WHERE StartDate >= @ReportStartDate 
      AND ISNULL(EndDate,GETDATE()) <= @ReportEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    *
from 
    @DimCustomers
where
    --gets where @ReportStartDate falls in range
    (@ReportStartDate >= StartDate and @ReportStartDate <= isnull(EndDate,getdate())) 
    or 
    --gets where @ReportEndDate falls in range
    (@ReportEndDate <= isnull(EndDate,getdate()) and @ReportEndDate >= StartDate) 
    or
    --gets where the range in data falls inside parameter range
    (@ReportStartDate < StartDate and @ReportEndDate > isnull(EndDate,getdate()))
```

Comment: @Aquillo that will evaluate true for both the first and second case so it'd be redundant. Fair idea though, for sure.